# Algebra of observables in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, observables

When reading books about Quantum Mechanics, it is generally stated (in a kind of axiomatic way) that in Quantum Mechanics, **the state of the system is represented by a vector in some Hilbert space $H$**, and that the **observables of the system correspond to Hermitian operators on $H$**.

On the other hand, when reading introductory books to the Standard Model, it is stated that we should look for a group of symmetry $G$ of a system and then consider the Hilbert spaces $H$ on which $G$ acts linearly. With this setup, we can associate an observable to each generator of $G$ and it will be a Hermitian operator. Also, the whole universal enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra associated to $G$ will provide Hermitian operators on $H$.

My question is: where are the observables from quantum mechanics supposed to come from? Are they all living in the universal enveloping algebra of the construction above? Is that necessary to introduce other mathematical structures to get a full description of the algebra of observables?

Comment: You're comparing two different things here: The algebra of observables consists of much more than the algebra of *symmetries*. It's strange that you claim that books on the "Standard Model" should focus on symmetries in contrast to ordinary quantum mechanics - symmetries have a similar importance in all of QM, not just QFT/the Standard Model, so it's unclear kind of answer you're looking for here

Comment: @ACuriousMind I'm not really claiming anything, I'm just confused. QM states that observables are Hermitian operators. Is there some way to justify this or should it be considered an axiom? Also, once the Hilbert space it set, can any Hermitian operator correspond to an observable or is it just some of them (if so, based on which criteria?)